# Creating a new wallet mobile application for newly created crypto currency

Tags: solidity, blockchain, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, cryptography

I am doing as a Intern in Apogee Tech Global in Bangalore on Blockchain for three months.
My commitments is to learn solidity language, build smart contracts, learn Ethereum and Hyperledger.
I learnt solidity language. I haven't yet practised more on solidity. Just learnt.
By using ERC20, I have created a new crypto currency in ropsten test network and also verified in ether scan.
I can also create real crypto currency in main ethereum network if ethers are available.

But, here the company employee told me to practise on solidity more. Also learn UI develpment part parallelly.
To do UI part, they said to learn Javascript.
I learnt javascript in codecademy. Now I am going through React.js.

Now, based on above criteria. Please suggest me the best path and suggestions to learn the required technologies to develop a crypto wallet and to build UI in prior time.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly discourage you to build your own crypto wallet if you are not familiar with the environment and all the challenges. Some of the things you only learn with experience, so you can't just read books or take courses. There are too many things that could go wrong when writing an own wallet.

Best would be to integrate some existing and battle-tested wallet into whatever platform you need. I guess choosing the right wallet depends on your environment.

But if it's just as a training exercise, first choose the technologies you want to use for building it. Javascript? Fine. Then decide on how to communicate with the blockchain. Infura? Own node? Fine. Then you should probably google for lots of tutorials and different guides on what all you need and start prototyping it.

Also, if you're in a hurry, all you can basically do is find some ready source codes online and hack them together.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to take a look at truffle and the truffle boxes they provide (http://truffleframework.com/boxes/). Pet Shop is a good one to start with learning how to create your first dApp. Apart from that you'll find medium has some nice articles which explain lots of things on ui and Dapp development in general.

Update: I also just found this website which packs lots of websites and articles about dApp development: https://dappnews.io/resources.